# $2f'(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)-f(-z)}{z^2} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function on a unit disc. Then how can we show that

$2f'(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)-f(-z)}{z^2} dz$ whenever $0<r<1$?

I think this has to do with Cauchy's integral formula since $2\pi i f'(0) = \int_{C_r} \frac{f(z)}{z^2}dz$. So it seems like we should have $\int_{C_r} \frac{f(z)}{z^2}dz = -\int_{C_r} \frac{f(-z)}{z^2}dz$. However, if I change $z$ to $-z$ then I get the opposite orientation so I think it should be $-\int_{-C_r} \frac{f(-z)}{z^2}dz$. How do we get this identity?

Comment: Are there really two integrals there? Shouldn't that be only the leftmost integral? And if not, what is the innermost integral? Over what region or what are its limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution $z \to -z$ does not change the orientation of the curve, it corresponds  to a shift $\phi \to \phi + \pi$ in the argument. Therefore $\int_{C_r} \frac{f(z)}{z^2}dz = -\int_{C_r} \frac{f(-z)}{z^2}dz$ is correct.

Alternatively you can apply Cauchy's integral formula to $g(z) = f(z) - f(-z)$, with $g'(0) = 2f'(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using holomorphic $\implies$ analytic: write
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$$
(with $a_n = f^{(n)}(0)$/n!)

Then,
$$
\frac{f(z)-f(-z)}{z^2} = \frac 1{z^2}(0 + 2a_1z + \cdots) = \frac{2a_1}z + \cdots
$$
and
$$
\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)-f(-z)}{z^2}\,dz= \hbox{residue of integrand in $0$} = \cdots
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  You can use Cauchy's differentiation formula:  $f^{(n)}(a)=\dfrac {n!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \dfrac {f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\operatorname dz$.

Let $g(z)=f(z)-f(-z)$.  Then $g'(0)=2f'(0)$.

Can you finish?

Comment: This is exactly what the OP mentions and tries to use in its question...

Comment: Ok.  I'll show how. @DonAntonio

Comment: @DonAntonio it isn't _exactly_ what,  as Cauchy's differentiation formula,  while a direct consequence of the integral formula,  is slightly different.